# Unexpected token error when setting Up React and Babel

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, babeljs

When setting Up React and Babel I'm experiencing the following syntax error:

```
ERROR in ./src/index.js
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js):
SyntaxError: Unexpected token (5:8)

  3 | 
  4 | const Index = () => {
> 5 |   return <div>Hello React</div>;
    |          ^
  6 | }
  7 | 
  8 | ReactDOM.render(<Index />, document.getElementById("index"));
```

This relates to an article - 'How to Create a React app from scratch using Webpack 4' which can be found on freeCodeCamp...

Did anyone get this too?

Thanks!

Comment: That isn't a syntax error. That's a pointer to where an error is, but you forgot the error message.

Comment: You also failed to include a [mcve]. Babel can handle that when correctly configured.

Comment: You probably don't have set up the JSX plugin (babel-plugin-transform-react-jsx
). There is a lot of good tools like create-react-app that will set everything for you, you should give it a try.

Comment: Just included error message...thanks!

Comment: you need to setup .babelrc file to include jsx es6 syntaxes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> npm install babel-loader babel-preset-react

Add this modules.
And in webpack configuration add following.

```
{ 
    test: /\.jsx?$/,    
    exclude: /node_modules/, 
    loader: "babel-loader", 
    query:
      {
        presets:['react']
      }
}
```

Comment: Great Happy coding :)